# How to set EmptyView in ListActivity

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I would like to display Empty View like "**`No Items Found`**" **in ListActivity** if it is Empty. I have searched more on sites and all suggestions for setEmptyView method of ListView only. Can you please guide for ListActivity?

Comment: is up to (and should not be a part of Adapter)... take a look at ListFragment source or use it ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getListView().setEmptyView(yourTextView);` method in ListActivity.

```
TextView emptyView = new TextView(mContext);
emptyView.setText("Empty List");
emptyView.setTextSize(25);
emptyView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

getListView().setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

**Edit**

I just found that Cyril Mottier wrote a [blog](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/06/20/listview-tips-tricks-1-handle-emptiness/) about this. It seems that it is exactly what you would like to do.

Comment: Please try to set the layout params of the text view. Most probably the text view is added on the page but it is invisible.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution as below

```
TextView emptyview = new TextView(this);
emptyview.setText("Empty List");
emptyview.setTextSize(25);

ListView currentlistview = getListView();

if(listadapter.size()==0)
((ViewGroup)currentlistview.getParent()).addView(emptyview);
```

I have to search more for the solution... ;)

Answer (score 0):

For add an empty view for `ListActivity` according too [source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/ListActivity.java):

1. Create a xml layout, for example `R.layout.list_activity`, with `ListView` and `TextView` with identifiers (required!) `android:id/list`, `android:id/empty`.

   ```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:padding="8dp"
   >
   <ListView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:id="@android:id/list"
   />
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@android:id/empty"
       android:text="@string/empty"
       android:gravity="center"
   />
   </LinearLayout>
   ```
2. Set this layout:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ){
       super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
       setContentView( R.layout.list_activity );
       //...
   }
   ```